# Two new user pages?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

Will MO be participating in this?

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big/?cb=1

Comment: Blech.  It will take two clicks instead of one to figure out what someone has been doing recently.  And it's seriously ugly.

Comment: I've not finished skimming that post/link, but in my opinion, Grimlock treat this kind of tomfoolery with scorn and rally Dinobots to join him seek return to Proper Ways

Comment: Also, I am inclined to agree with Andy on the aesthetics.

Comment: I see this has been implemented at math.stackexchange. I agree with Andy and Yemon, and annoyed that it is, apparently, a fait accompli.

Comment: Another point is that the Profile pages (which are now to be the default pages) would seem to be moving our beloved site into a social media direction (think FB, Twitter) that many MO users explicitly do not want.

Comment: @ToddTrimble the general fact that, and how, the profile pages will be changed was discussed over the period of a year with plenty of community input, e.g., they were live as a test on [meta.se] for quite some time. (If you think MO wants some special-casing you might want to start a discussion about it.) A good point to start to trace the process might be [this initial post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226177/the-profile-page-is-getting-a-makeover-part-one) and then following the dupe-links.

Comment: I have just seen some of these profiles on MSE and now can't decided which I dislike more: the aesthetics of the design, or the "banter" of the SO blogpost which is linked to by Bjorn.

Comment: I think, to save time and trouble, we should color the user names brown for those in favor of the migration to 2.0 from MathOverflow 1.0, purple for those against, and black for those who abstain or are/were undecided.  (Or have a committee decide on the color scheme, for those who have a few weeks to kill.)  That way the color says it all, and will save a lot of future typing, trust me.  If you weren't expecting this sort of thing after the migration, you weren't thinking ahead.  Gerhard "I'll Take The Color Green" Paseman, 2015.04.19

Comment: Oh, and before the discussion gets out of hand, we have an agreement to part ways and do things our own way (with our own servers, maintenance team, software support, as well as giving up all or most of the benefits accrued from the migration, etc.).  All those ready to pull the ripcord on the emergency chute, raise your hands.  Gerhard "Still Thinking About Hand Raising" Paseman, 2015.04.19

Comment: @quid I *plead* guilty to not knowing this was coming until recently, although I certainly don't *feel* guilty about that or that I've somehow been remiss. Mostly I tune into meta.stackexchange when I have to look up some point of policy to do my "job" here (which is volunteer work, as you know). My comments before were in view of just such a discussion of "special-casing" as you put it: this is just the type of thing that probably had people leery of the migration. I would love an opt-in policy for MO users.

Comment: @ToddTrimble I didn't mean to assign any guilt, I mainly meant to point out that it was *[and is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253450/)* possible  to influence how the profile pages look. I feel a mountain is made out of a mole-hill here. To me hardly anything seems to have changed; the navigation via  tabs is now more nested, which has up-sides and down-sides. The actual information provided is almost unchanged. I would be curious what specifically made you say that the change makes the site move into a social media direction. (I'd be against this, but I don't see it.)

Comment: @quid I read encouragement towards that direction on the blog post: "The Profile Page lets you show others a summary of what you’re all about. Share your interests, favorite charities, or your Twitter, Github, and SO Careers activity." See also the illustrative page of Tambo which lists her music interests, what she's currently learning, etc. This is the kind of fluff that I expect many MO users are not interested in -- we come here for the *mathematics*, not to check up on personal interests (which is apparently supposed to be a point of attraction for the default page).

Comment: @ToddTrimble that part seems to refer to the "about me" that existed always. (The sole change being that it is now top-center rather then top-right and perhaps it's very slightly larger.) Everybody can and always could write everything there (as long as it is not offensive). To me explanation is a completely generic way of saying "write whatever you like there" (the expl. must make sense for 100+ sites); but example-text seems except for three/four words completely about the subject of the respective site. Anyway, in practice, the *existing* texts would be shown before and  after the change.

Comment: @quid I know about "About Me". My point is that the new design is putting the fluff front and center on the default page, and that I personally prefer having everything consolidated on a single user page, and that **that should be an option**. (The way I use user pages, aside from moderator activities, is somewhat along the lines of what they predict I won't be interested in: stuff on users' activity pages (past questions, answers, comments mainly). Not interested much in personal stuff which used to be unobtrusively off to the side, and that I now must click past to get what I really want.)

Comment: @ToddTrimble why not explain, perhaps at a more appropriate place, how exactly you think it should be an option (per site, per user what they show, per user what they see, still something else). With *specific* proposals one can hope for modifications, with just saying "seriously ugly" rather not.

Comment: For reference: the proposal that which page one gets shown should be user-selectable [was raised](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253659) and declined, yet with the add-on it might be revisited. (A reasoning might be to wait and to see how many actually click through  to the other page/tab.) Anyway, this behavior, if desired, can be achieved easily with a user-script, too. Linked on the linked post.

Comment: @quid Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Link appears to be dead. Try https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-on/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You think we'd forget you?

MO isn't live yet because the new pages require an update to each site's CSS, and [we're still working through about half the sites on the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed).  As soon as it's finished, MO will get the new profile.

Comment: I am really looking forward to the update. Being also used to  some other pages in the network, the current look of MO starts to feels a bit clumsy.

Comment: Preferring to sound more like a curmudgeon than an ungrateful user, I and many others would appreciate this new style to be a user selectable toggle, so that I (and doubtless many other users of this forum) could choose to opt-in to this style change.  Further, while the phrase "people reached" sounds noble and progressive, I think something more realistic like "views tallied" is to be preferred, at least until we raise the ceilings and widen doorways to accommodate head growth. Gerhard "Ego Is Already Big Enough" Paseman, 2015.04.19

Comment: I find the new user Profile page---with its Top Network Posts cutting across all Stack Exchange sites, etc.---more informative than the current page. I'm with @quid, looking forward to the new pages.