# Next badge appeared and disappeared

Tags: discussion, user-interface, design

A few days ago I noticed that under the recent achievements tab there were two status bars showing how far along you were to the next privilege and next badge. I liked this but it has now disappeared. Why did it go away?

Comment: I don’t know what’s a recent achievement tab, but a next privilege bar is shown at http://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges (no idea about badges).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek It's at the top next to the inbox and stackexchange tabs. Hover over it and it gives itself that name.

Comment: Yes, the experiment is over. The oddity with some users seeing it on one device/browser combination and not others was the result of a broken experiment setup. Even so, we got enough data to lead us to believe the feature was not useful to the majority of users. Personally, I found them an unwanted distraction from the information I was looking for when I clicked the notification. Eventually, the [new profile pages](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/2225/36770) will be implemented here and you'll be able to track your badges from there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was apparently some A/B testing of this some days ago, see Anna Lear's comment [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265841/can-we-have-an-option-to-disable-the-new-badge-privilege-section-in-the-achiev#comment862722_265841):

> We're currently A/B testing this feature [next badge/privilege progress in the achievements drop-down] to see how it performs. ...  No promises on whether we'd add an option to disable it (assuming we decide to keep it), but I will say that if we see overall positive results in user behaviour, we'll put more time into making the next badge/privilege tracker more usable in the dropdown.

If you are no longer seeing it, I guess the testing is over, and SE will decide what to do with this. (Note that some users saw this while working on some computers, but not while working on others.)

Answer (score 2):

Note that, if you liked this feature, it is still available on your user page. Head to your user page and select the Activity tab in the top left (if not already selected). You should see something like this:

[image]

As the example shows, you can also find out other people's next badge if you want to.

Comment: Yes, I very much like the activity page. I asked this question a couple of days before this latest site update. There is certainly no reason now to have the next badge appear on the achievements tab.