# New interface - empty rectangles in the reputation column

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

I've got new interface and I like it, but there is something strange:

[image]

Some numbers are supposed to be there, right? They are present on other StackExchange sites with this interface

Comment: Good catch! You might follow the request though: "This update should retro-actively fix most of the old design bugs. If you see any new bugs, or old ones not yet fixed, please post an answer here to let us know!" and post it over there http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2467/site-updates-are-live

Comment: Since it was seen by the right person already, my comment is obsolete.

Comment: Well I did it already anyway :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch! We will fix this in the next production build.

Comment: Under reputation panel under activity tab, for accepted answers, I get solid green rectangles as opposed to green rectangles with a number indicating what rep I got for having that answer accepted.  Gerhard "I Like That Green Shade" Paseman, 2015.09.25

Comment: A fix is coming. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Sorry for bothering you but I don't know what to do - there seems to be another bug which is indicated in [another question](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2870/text-on-some-buttons-has-become-unrecognizable); it has been up for several days without any feedback from the developer team. Maybe you know what is the current status of it?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე thanks for the heads up. We'll fix it.