# Text on some buttons has become unrecognizable

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Very recently (I think today) the buttons with "Post your answer", "Answer your question" and some others became black, with the text hardly readable.

[image]

With me it happens on Windows 10 with latest builds of both Chrome and Waterfox.

Not a bug strictly speaking, but...

Comment: Appears for me on main (but apparently not meta) on a Mac running OS X 10.10.5 in latest version on Chrome.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Confirmed - on meta text is white on dark gray background, quite clearly visible

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would count as a bug (I also don't see the text on those buttons on the main site; Chrome 49.something on Windows 10.) The [meta-tag:design] tag should probably be added to this question. (I would do it myself, but my paltry reputation does not allow me.)

Comment: @arjafi Done, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I see this problem, too.  Safari 9.1, MacOS 10.11.4

Comment: Here on Meta, I see the "Add Comment" in white, but when I mouse over it, the text disappears...

Comment: On the main site, the black becomes blacker on mouseover, too.

Comment: I see this problem, too, with Firefox 45, Windows 7. And also Gerald Edgar's observation.

Comment: I see it here (both for answers and comments) on Chrome 49, Windows 10.

Comment: Chrome on Windows 7, same problem.

Comment: Firefox 46 on Ubuntu 12.04, same issue

Comment: Firefox 45 on Debian Stretch, same problem. I think we can safely say it is independent of both browser and operating system.

Comment: No one mentioned Internet Explorer on Windows.  Is it not used any more?  Or maybe only people with the problem read this thread.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Just tried Microsoft Edge (browser coming with Windows 10) out of curiosity. The "Sign up" button is the same faintly visible black-on-black.

Comment: It is certainly a bug: "Indicates you've found an erroneous or unexpected behaviour in the system that needs to be fixed." Well, it is unexpected and  erroneous and it needs to be fixed.

Comment: Is there a way to ping the devs? In theory, they should be watching for questions tagged as bug, but clearly they aren't.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Not sure if this was a right thing to do but I've used [another question](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2470/new-interface-empty-rectangles-in-the-reputation-column) about a bug to ask  [Kurtis Beavers](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/users/75292/kurtis-beavers) who provided prompt feedback there.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek SE employee activity is usually pretty low over the weekends. Since this question popped up on a Friday, I'm willing to give the devs the benefit of the doubt for now. Lots of [meta-tag:bug] reports come in across the network, and there are a limited number of people looking at them. Admittedly, there probably would be faster turnaround if an SE employee was actually active on MO.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek ... So ... do not conclude the devs do not watch here, when it could just be that it is the weekend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the issue. This will be fixed with our next production build.

Comment: I hope the next production build is soon.

Comment: @ChrisRamsey Should be corrected now.

Comment: It is, thank you!